Formatting getting disturb while opening file using base64(Alignment,Font Colour,FontSize etc.)
My Environment
Platform : PC desktop
Host: Power Point
Office version number: Microsoft® PowerPoint® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2404 Build 16.0.17531.20140) 64-bit
Operating System: Windows 11 pro
Hi Team,
Here is my code snippet which is I used to open PPT using base64.
async function loadslide(mybase64) {
     try {
         await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
             context.presentation.load("slides");
             await context.sync();
             const slides = context.presentation.slides;
             const slideCount = slides.getCount();
             slides.load("items");
             await context.sync();
             slides.items.map((slide) => {
                 slide.delete();
             });
             await context.sync();
             context.presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64(mybase64);
             await context.sync();
             Loader("hide", translate('Addin_J_302'), "S");

         });
     } catch (e) {
         console.log("e", e);
     }
 }

After Opening my PPT file using code its alignment getting disturb I'm attaching file here for reference
RefenceDocument

I don't see the difference between what you are expecting and what you are getting. Please state it explicitly.

@RickKirkham As you can see in attachment (ReferenceDocument)  as example there is screenshot of expectedoutput and erroroutput.    As example just try ExpectedOP PPT2.png and ErrorFilePPT2.png in that you cann see my text alignment and font size is changed so one there is other 2 file screenshot is there and for refrerence I'm also attached Origina file as(PPT1.pptx , PPT2.pptx , PPT3.pptx )
